# What is the regex to match this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider these sentences:

> apple is 2kg
>   apple banana mango is 2kg
>   apple apple apple is 6kg
>   banana banana banana is 6kg

Given that "apple", "banana", and "mango" are the only fruits, what would be the regex to extract the fruit name(s) that appear in the start of the sentence?

I wrote this regex (https://regex101.com/r/fY8bK1/1):

```
^(apple|mango|banana) is (\d+)kg$
```

but this only matches if a single fruit is in the sentence.

How do I extract all the fruit names?

The expected output, for all 4 sentences, should be:

> apple, 2
>   apple banana mango, 2
>   apple apple apple, 6
>   banana banana banana, 6

Comment: Please post a clear sample of output .

Comment: Try  this regex expression `^(apple|mango|banana| )+ is (\d+)kg$`

Comment: Check [`^([\w ]+) is (\d+)kg$`](https://regex101.com/r/xZ7rB5/2)

Comment: remove the last space  from your `()` as it will match ..'

Comment: @PedroLobito Updated.

Comment: @roroinpho21 your regex only matches a single fruit. I am trying to match all of them. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
^((?:apple|mango|banana| )+) is (\d+)kg\s?$/gmi
```

---

**DEMO**

https://regex101.com/r/dO1rR7/1

---

**Explanation**

```
^((?:apple|mango|banana| )+) is (\d+)kg\s?$/gmi

^ assert position at start of a line
1st Capturing group ((?:apple|mango|banana| )+)
    (?:apple|mango|banana| )+ Non-capturing group
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        1st Alternative: apple
            apple matches the characters apple literally (case sensitive)
        2nd Alternative: mango
            mango matches the characters mango literally (case sensitive)
        3rd Alternative: banana
            banana matches the characters banana literally (case sensitive)
        4th Alternative:  
             matches the character  literally
 is matches the characters  is literally (case sensitive)
2nd Capturing group (\d+)
    \d+ match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
kg matches the characters kg literally (case sensitive)
\s? match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
    Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of a line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: holy mackrel! explanation, please :D

Comment: *salute* I could never have figured that out. :D

Comment: `'fooapplebar is 2kg'` will match here

Comment: @paul I've updated the answer, now it only matches the fruits.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers & I was having a hard time choosing which one so I chose yours because you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use grouping like this:

```
^((?:apple|mango|banana)(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*) is (\d+)kg$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD1sW6/2)

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group inside a capturing (`(...)`) group so as not to create a mess in the output.

The `((?:apple|mango|banana)(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*)` group matches:

- `(?:apple|mango|banana)` - any value from the alternative list delimited with alternation `|` operator. If you plan to match whole words only, put `\b` at both ends of the subpattern.
- `(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*` matches 0 or more sequences of...

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
  - `(?:apple|mango|banana)` - any of the alternatives.

Snippet:

```js
var re = /^((?:apple|mango|banana)(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*) is (\d+)kg$/gm; 
var str = 'apple is 2kg\napple banana mango is 2kg\napple apple apple is 6kg\nbanana banana banana is 6kg';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.write(m[1] + "," + m[2] + "<br/>");
}

document.write("<b>appleapple is 2kg</b> matched: " + 
     /^((?:apple|mango|banana)(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*) is (\d+)kg$/.test("appleapple is 2kg"));
```

Comment: `'appleapple is 2kg'` matches this string, you're close though!

Comment: Also, the last line of the OP example has an extra space before the line break.

Comment: @PedroLobito Oh no! That extra space at the end was by mistake :)

Comment: No problem, on my regex it's optional `\s?`

Comment: I updated to exclude cases like `'appleapple is 2kg'`.

Comment: Now works as I'd expect (not sure about `'apple_________apple is 1kg'` where `_` is space, but anyway) so you get my vote, but now I'll be OCD and say I'd really feel happier about the `while` if it was organised `null !== (expr)`, and `document.write`? :(

Comment: If there must be one space only between fruit, remove `+` from `\s`. The code is a demo. It is used only to show the results of the regex. `alert` does not work on my computer, so I am using the quickest `document.write`. My son needs the computer, I will be away now for some time.

Comment: @PaulS. `document.write()` seems to me like a perfectly valid way to print output in the code snippet

Comment: To make the patten case-insensitive, the `/i` modifier must be added: [`var re = /^((?:apple|mango|banana)(?:\s+(?:apple|mango|banana))*)\s+is\s+(\d+)kg\s*$/gmi;`](https://regex101.com/r/rC7kE2/3). Currently accepted answer allows even [`"  is 45kg"`](https://regex101.com/r/rC7kE2/1) input (2 spaces before `is`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var re = /^((?:(?:apple|banana|mango)(?= ) ?)+) is (\d+)kg$/gm;

re.exec('apple banana mango is 2kg');
// ["apple banana mango is 2kg", "apple banana mango", "2"]
```

What is making this different to the other answers? The `(?= ) ?` after the fruit options forces a space as the next character but doesn't capture it unless there are more fruits (or you double spaced the *is*).

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Use this in a `while` loop to get all the results from a multi-line string.

---

The `gm` flags here let this *RegExp* be applied to the same *String* multiple times using `re.exec`, where new lines match `$^`. However, the `g` flag causes `str.match` to behave differently.

If you want an independent test for each string you could continue using `re.exec` or remove these flags and use `str.match` instead

```
var re = /^((?:(?:apple|banana|mango)(?= ) ?)+) is (\d+)kg$/; // notice flags gone

'apple banana mango is 2kg'.match(re);
// ["apple banana mango is 2kg", "apple banana mango", "2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(((apple|mango|banana)\s*)+) is (\d+)kg$/$1,$4/gm
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/sA4aW7/2

So you start from here, one of:

```
(apple|mango|banana)
```

Lets get the eventual whitespace separating repetitions:

```
(apple|mango|banana)\s*
```

and all (one at the least) of the repetitions:

```
((apple|mango|banana)\s*)+
```

Need to add an additional group, because you want a single group capturing the lot:

```
(((apple|mango|banana)\s*)+)
```

Add this point, `$1` (the outermost group) will contain "banana banana banana ..."; the fourth your weight. Add your own `?:` to avoid capturing inner groups [if you like](https://regex101.com/r/mH1zI2/1).